# Using .find() method in JS to get nested objects like in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, matrix

I was trying to get an object among several nested objects by means of a coincidence using .find() in js, something like it is done in mongodb that using the '.find()' method and placing some hint you can get similar results in js, actually this .find() method in js as far as I understand is only for arrays but I wanted to know if it was even possible to do this that I have been trying...

here is the code....

```js
const arrayLike = {
  length: 1,
  people: {
        person: {
            first name: 'rafa',
            last name: 'rivas',
            age: 20
        },
        person: {
            first name: 'miguel',
            last name: 'blades',
            age: 23
        },
        person: {
            first name: 'mario',
            last name: 'perez',
            age: 93
        },
    }
};
console.log(Array.prototype.find.call(arrayLike, (x) => x ));
```

already there I got lost with the results that it gives me too, I would expect from that console to return at least the array('people') by console but it comes out 'undefined'.

Comment: The `people` property is not a [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). Its a [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). Your "people" obejct is also invalid, because a key has to be unique in a object. I think you are mixing here some things.

Comment: well yes friend, actually the code has a couple of errors but I think I have achieved what I was looking for, look at this function that I did, it is a disaster of code but it works, now the thing is to see how I could do to summarize and accommodate a bit the look code:

Although, as it is, it only has a scope of 3 nesting levels, do you know how I could optimize that function?

Answer (score 0):

```
function finc(obj, texto) {
let result;
for (let clave in obj){
    let f = obj[clave];

    if(f === texto){
        result = obj;
    }else{
        result = 0;
        for (let clave2 in f) {
            let s = f[clave2];
            
            if(s === texto){
                result = f;
            }else{
                result = 1;
                for (let clave3 in s){
                    let th = s[clave3]
                    console.log(th);

                    if(th === texto){
                        result = s;
                        console.log(result, ' d')
                    }else{
                        result = 2
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
return result;
```

}